# Planes are floating away or clipping

Tags: camera

For some strange reason planes I put onto surface perpendicular to it clip and do not show in full. What can be the reason? They are clipped even more when I move camera
[image]

[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cnlkkdi4vckgz1/forestRun.blend?dl=0)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cnlkkdi4vckgz1/forestRun.blend?dl=0 hope it works